# Add images to JButton in Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I am a new programmer and have just started using Eclipse. Previously, I used JGRASP and when I wanted to add an image to a button all I did was to create an `Image` folder within the class's folder and write:

`setIcon(newImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/name.png")));`

I tried the same thing with Eclipse but I get a `main:NullPointerException` error.
I already read another post and added a `source folder` to my project named `Images` but nothing changed.  The following is the code segment I have an issue with:

`resetButton.setIcon(newImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Images/helpIcon.png")));`

Comment: May you please provide the directory structure of the project. Please see if this post, regarding how to [add images to Java Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), helps in the given direction or not.

Comment: Try to create *package* `Images` and move your image there.

Comment: @nIcEcOw has created a helpful [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659) to [tag:embedded-resource]s, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 6):

You are on right way. You had added resource folder. This is the additional root for your resources. Here, in this folder (as root) you have to create /Image folder and then put files into it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also place your resources in the root "ttt" folder [Although this is not as professional a solution as the one Alex suggested] and refer to them by name, without any package details.

Comment: You right. It will work in Eclipse then. But it will not be deployed to jar file.